# SQL command like R table function

Tags: sql

I am a beginner for SQL.
If I have a table **tab** like blow:

### [image]

In **R**, I can use **table(tab$prediction, tab$result_code)** to get the table which look like confusion table. But I don't known how to create this table by using SQL command. Is it possible to get the table contain counts between prediction column and result_code column?

Comment: You want to create the table? Do you also want to do the inserts? What counts do you want to save? (But it feels more like getting counts by aggregating over the data using the ```COUNT``` function)

Comment: If you want to create a table use `CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(Prediction int,Result_code int);` Check [**Tutorial**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1):

From your data, the column "prediction" was used as the actual prices and the "result_code" column as predicted values.

As the comments advise, you can perform a `COUNT` over the two columns to get the occurrences. This table is used as the base to create the confusion matrix and is names as `TEMP`.
After creating the `TEMP` table, you perform a `PIVOT` to restructure the table to get the format of the confusion matrix.

```
SELECT prediction, "0", "1", "2"
FROM
(
SELECT [prediction],[result_code],COUNT(*) as Occurences
FROM [Your_Schema].[dbo].[Your_Database]
GROUP BY [prediction],[result_code]
)Temp
PIVOT
(
MAX(Occurences)
FOR result_code in ("0","1","2")
)PIV
```